# Rails object.valid? with arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Is it possible to pass :symbols to the valid? method so that I can define if the object is valid up to a certain point?

Eg. if I have an object Person and want to call `Person.valid?(:basic_info)` and it will return true only if a certain subset of fields (say name & gender) are present?

I saw something that I thought might be of use but cannot get it working, it's conditional validations http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#conditional-validation , in particular grouping conditional validations, but I couldn't get it working...

Can anyone help me out here please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work using conditional validations, so now i can use `.valid?(:basic)` say for when i only want to check that the person has a name with the call...

```
validates_presence_of :name, :when => [:basic]
```

Documentation here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/valid%3F

This way I can have the object return true when calling `.valid?` even when it doesn't have a name, good times...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there already present like this however you can write a method on your own like following

```
def is_valid_field?(field)
  self.valid?
  self.errors[field].blank?
end
```

and then just `person.is_valid_field?(:basic_info)`

Answer (score 1):

To validate `basic_info` you'll have to define a custom validator:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :basic_info_present

  def basic_info_present
    if name.blank? || gender.blank?
      errors.add(:basic_info, "can't be in blank")
    end
  end
end
```

If you then want to see if there are errors on the specific field, you can use @Salil's approach.

Note however that since there is no actual attribute called `basic_info` in your model, the validation errors here will not come up in forms, etc. (although they will be in the `errors` hash). That may or may not be what you want.